Pronunciation of "alleluya" in 17th century French latin
Marc-Antoine Charpentier's "O sacrum convivium", comp contains the word "alleluya" [sic]. I am wondering how it would have been pronounced by French speakers at the time, so around the second half of the 17th century.
I am especially hesitating between /alelyja/ and /alelɥija/.

The current French pronunciation is /a.le.lu.ja/ (definitely not /ly/).
In Gallican Latin, words were mostly pronounced as if they were written in French. This pronunciation was the "official" one until the sixties. The U was keeping its /y/ sound in it.
Alleluia was then likely pronounced /a.le.ly.ja/.

Traité complet de la prononciation française dans la seconde moitié du 19e siècle., 1890.

The quotation seems to me to suggest more like /a.le.ly.i.a/, from “…l’u et l’i donnent aussi deux sons égaux en quantité”, though it’s certainly a bit ambiguous?  But I suppose the Charpentier setting (or other musical settings) may well clarify whether the composer expected 4 or 5 syllables.
